# How to handle double quotes in Pattern.compile?

Tags: java, regex, beanshell

I have the following piece of regex which works in an online regex tester:

```
  assetName">([^"]+)</span>
```

I want to use this in a Beanshell Script like this:

```
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("assetName">([^"]+)</span>");
```

How do I handle the double quotes here? Thanks

Comment: Most probably `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("assetName\">([^\"]+)</span>");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in Java, just use a slash in front of the double quotation mark:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("assetName\">([^\"]+)</span>");
```